# How to find "grouped" or "uneaven" data?

Tags: numpy, statistics

I need to find if thousands of arrays have data that are "grouped" into lower or higher that are adjacent(correct word to use?) values or not.

`a` is "uneaven" and `b, c` have grouped data. I need some way to separate the a:s from b and c:s. Maybe there are som statistical measurement to use? I thought about using the time it takes to sort the arrays to separate them but it feels uncertain.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,10,0,10,0,10,0,10]) #Very uneaven _'_'_'_'
b = np.array([0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10]) #two groups ____''''
c = np.array([0,0,10,10,10,10,0,0]) #three groups __''''__

import timeit
for name, arr in zip(['a','b','c'], [a,b,c]):
    print(name, ' ', round(timeit.timeit(lambda: np.sort(a, axis=None), number=10000), 5))

#The most sorted array is the slowest to sort...
#a   0.01802
#b   0.01807
#c   0.01716

#This work if the array is sorted. But if I sort the arrays all become grouped... (also array "a")
for name, arr in zip(['a','b','c'], [a,b,c]):
    if arr[:4].mean() == arr[4:].mean():
        print(name, ' ', 'uneaven')
    else:
        print(name, ' ', 'grouped')

a   uneaven
b   grouped
c   uneaven
```

Comment: You may have more luck on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ . However, I think your question is unclear: are you trying to find whether a set of data is very regular, or if a member of your combined data is part of a subset of it? Perhaps some multimodal test will help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution#Statistical_tests , but I think that you should start by graphing your data. Then add a linear trendline and see what it looks like for a better idea of your data.

Comment: What is the exact definition of being grouped and uneven? Whether having any element consecutively?

Comment: I haven decided yet. The data are heights of trees (or ground when 0) and Im trying to find tree stand borders. Next step is some machine learning algorithm then I probably need to adjust the group or not grouped borders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can calculate the sum of change/difference between all pair of values in each array:

```
for name, arr in zip(['a','b','c'], [a,b,c]):
    sum_of_change = sum([abs(val1-val2) for val1,val2 in zip(arr,arr[1:])])
    print(name, ' ', sum_of_change)

a   70 #A more unsorted array will have larger sum
b   10
c   20
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A pattern in your data is the rate of change in consecutive numbers. The sensitivity is adjustable with the `threshold` argument.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,10,0,10,0,10,0,10]) 
b = np.array([0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10]) 
c = np.array([0,0,10,10,10,10,0,0])
d = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

def classify(x, threshold = .2):
    t = (x[1:] != x[:-1]).sum() / (len(x)-1)
    return 'grouped' if t < threshold else 'uneven'

for i in [a,b,c,d]:
    print(classify(i))
```

Output

```
uneven
grouped
uneven
grouped
```